# Redirect Sub-Sub Domain to Sub-Domain Without Knowing Base Domain

Tags: nginx

If I want to redirect *.plex.example.com -> plex.example.com in Nginx, I can do

```
server {
    listen                  443 ssl http2;
    listen                  [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name             *.plex.example.com;

    return                  301 https://plex.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

How can I do this more generally? Is there a snippet that would redirect the above example and say *.plex.test.net -> plex.test.net. More generally, redirect *.plex.domain.tld -> plex.domain.tld.

Not sure if this is possible, but bonus points if you can figure out how to redirect *.subdomain.domain.tld -> subdomain.domain.tld.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config you provided would not work without browser security complains unless you have a valid wildcard certificate/key for a `*.plex.example.com` domain.
You can try to catch main domain name in a named regex match:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate </path/to/certificate>;
    ssl_certificate_key </path/to/key>;
    server_name  ~.*\.plex\.(?<domain>[^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$;
    return 301 https://plex.$domain$request_uri;
}
```

But again, you need a valid certificate for all possible domain names.

Comment: Works great! I left the SSL configuration out of the question for brevity, but yes, I've included my ssl configuration and it works!